# Hamel basis and real algebraic numbers

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, real-numbers, rational-numbers, hamel-basis

Is the following picture correct

[image]

Mainly: is it true that a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and that it contains the real algebraic numbers? If so, is there any reference for this?

Comment: There is no such thing as "the" Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$. Rather, some-but-not-all subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ are Hamel bases. To be precise, $X$ is a Hamel basis iff every real can be written as a linear combination with rational coefficients of finitely many elements of $X$ in exactly one way. This means that in particular $X$ cannot contain (for example) two rational numbers. So it is **very false** that any Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$ contains the algebraic numbers. What is true is that if $X$ is a Hamel basis of $\mathbb{R}$, then $X$ *does* contain a non-algebraic number.

Comment: I know that the [last time](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488798/) you tried to answer this question, it didn't go well, but please don't delete questions and re-post.

Comment: @TheoBendit Provided people are respectful towards what is being asked, I won't do it.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Great answer. Thank you

Comment: @NoahSchweber is then true to say that any Hamel basis contains, at most, one rational number?

Comment: @samwolfe Yes, that's right.

Comment: Why do you want to consider real algebraic numbers in connection with a Hamel basis? Is there some context to number theory?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Not necessarily, I just wanted to represent all these different sets in a single Venn-like scheme, if possible (for a write-up I am doing on these sets). However, now I have realised that it might not be as straightforward as I initially thought, and unfortunately, I missed some elementary properties of Hamel bases, as Noah Schweber mentioned.