# Is this arrangement of subsets of number sets correct?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, real-numbers

Is the following arrangement of subsets of number sets true?

$$\mathbb{N} \subset \mathbb{Z} \subset \mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{A_\mathbb{R}} \subset \mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{C} \subset \mathbb{C}\cup \left \{ \infty  \right \}$$

My set theory instructor says it is not.

Comment: Is the first one actually $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: My mistake. I edited it.

Comment: To get a better response from the community, try showing any work/thinking you've done regarding the problem. Also, the title should contain just the question and not the "my set theory instructor says it is not?"

Comment: A similar (but different) question was asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488809/hamel-basis-and-real-algebraic-numbers?noredirect=1#comment9415597_4488809) a few hours ago.

Comment: Why not ask your instructor what's wrong with it?

Comment: Well, from what was described. Each set is not completely contained within the other; However, there exists an embedding. But to me, it is clear that every natural number can be found in the set of integers. Every integer in the set of rationals. Every rational in the set of algebraic reals, and so on. If every element of a set is 'contained' within another. Doesn't that meet the definition of a 'subset'?.

Comment: @CodyS The context that this is your *set theory* professor is relevant here. It's common to construct $\mathbb C$ as the set of ordered pairs of elements of $\mathbb R$ with certain operations. Then (e.g. under the Kuratowski definition of ordered pair) $(\pi,0)$ is not the same as $\pi$ so we don't have $\mathbb R\subset\mathbb C$.

Comment: An algebraist might define the complex numbers as the set of cosets of the ideal generated by the polynomial $x^2+1$ in the ring of polynomials with real coefficients. By that definition, the reals are certainly not a subset of the complexes, since numbers aren't cosets. All we can say is the there is a subset of the complexes isomorphic as a field to the reals.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the possible objection would be at $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$. At issue is whether a real number $x$ is the same object as the complex number $x+0i$. One could probably argue either way on that one, but in a very strict sense, I would say they are different since they live in different sets. When working with complex numbers we often write, say, $3$ when strictly we mean $3+0i$.

Comment: So are the two numbers equivalent? is $ 3 = 3+0i $?

Comment: @CodyS It depends on who you ask, the day of the week, and whether they have pedantry mode engaged .  Most will define $\mathbb{C}$ from $\mathbb{R}$ and $x + 0i$ will not be the same as $x$.  However, they might follow with redefining $\mathbb{R}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and it will be that $x+0i =x$.